# Why is a singlet state potential greater than triplet state potential in the Feshbach resonance experiment?

Tags: atomic-physics, scattering, fermions, cold-atoms

I googled the Feshbach resonance in the Wikipedia and I have some problems. In German Wikipedia, they consider Li-6 molecule as an example.

For these two different spin configurations(singlet and triplet states), they have different potential curve as the following picture(from Wikipedia), which means they have different ground state energy.

[image]

The red one is for triplet state and the blue one is for singlet state. The dashed line means the energy of incoming particles.

In this picture, there is a cross point between triplet and singlet state potential curves. After that the singlet state potential curve is higher than triplet state potential curve.

$\textbf{My question is how it is achieved.}$ I could not understand and personally think that is wrong.

For large distance, the interaction between two Li-6 atoms is only Leonard-Jones potential. This potential is independent of internal state.

But even in the environment of external magnetic field, the singlet state could not be influenced by this external field because its total spin angular momentum is zero there is no projection along the magnetic field. So I expect the potential curve should be negative as its original curve at large distance.

For the triplet state, only $S_z=\pm1$ states are influenced by the magnetic field. So for $S_z=1$ the shift is downward and $S_z=-1$ the shift is upward.(I use $H=-\vec{S}\cdot\vec{B}$)

So if I pick up $S_z=-1$ I should get a result that the triplet state potential curve is upper the singlet state potential curve, and the cross point does not exist.

So I constantly got a result that triplet state is closed channel and singlet state is open channel. However, the story is reverse.